# Android paging library is not being fired at all

Tags: android, paging, androidx, android-architecture-components, android-paging-library

So I am new to the Paging Library and I am getting a problem. I am using [this](https://medium.com/@chet.deva/android-paging-for-network-uncovered-b9cb85ca637b) tutorial to try and page over the network. The problem is that none of the paging code is called at all.

I have tried checking a number of solutions and all seem to point towards the adapter. So I have done the following:
1. I have used the PagedListAdapter
2. I have also called the `getItem(position)` in the adapter as well.
3. Some have stated that not setting `setPageSize()` in the `PagedList.Config.Builder()` may be an issue. I have set that as well.

However, for the life of me, nothing seems to work. I could use some help with this, which is why I have uploaded the whole project [here](https://github.com/Fbada006/PagingBu).

Thanks.

Comment: what doesn't exactly work?

Comment: The call to `loadInitial` is never fired so there is no network call and subsequently no data to display.

Comment: post some code please

Comment: I have uploaded the whole project on GitHub. The link is in the question.

Comment: There is no Paging Library in the code on Github. It's a ListAdapter that gets its value from a LiveData observer that downloads stuff (hopefully) with coroutines. No Paging.

Comment: Hey @EpicPandaForce I have updated the question with the correct link. Apologies about the first code. And yes, the initial code with Coroutines and the ListAdapter works.